# How to generate all permutations with repetitions /make x amount of nested for functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, permutation

I am trying to create a function for my script to generate all possible permutations with repetition. I cant use any import modules so no itertools. (its for a project to solve a FLP problem which explicitly states no itertools).

Basically, I would like the function to do this.

It should accept two parameters, the list that contains the objects to take from, and the number of objects that can be taken.

For example, if the number of objects that can be taken is 3, and the *ListA* of objects to take from is [0,1,2,3], the function should pretty much do the below code or output the same result.

```
res = []
for i in ListA:
    for x in ListA:
        for y in ListA:
            res.append([i,x,y])
return res
```

I just dont know how to implement make X amount of nested for functions in python. Can someone give me a hand or point me in the right direction on what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListA = [0, 1, 2, 3]
n = 3


def func(ListA, n):
    res = [[l] for l in ListA]
    for i in range(n-1):
        res = [r+[l] for r in res for l in ListA]
    return res


res_Michael = func(ListA, n)

res = []
for i in ListA:
    for x in ListA:
        for y in ListA:
            res.append([i, x, y])


print(res_Michael == res)
# True
```

---

## `res = [[l] for l in ListA]`

Make init list like:

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
```

We need iter the elems, and concat it later:

```
[   [0, 0], ..., [0, 3], 
    [1, 0], ..., [1, 3], ...
]
```

```
for i in range(n-1):
```

Because res had been inited, so we concat only `(n-1) times`

## `res = [r+[l] for r in res for l in ListA]`

### `r+[l]`

`type of r is list`

`r+[l]` means `concat list r and [l]`

l is a `number` in ListA,

so

```
[l]
```

is `a list with only one element`

### `for r in res for l in ListA`

Your output is:

```
[0, 0, 0] then [0, 0, 1]
```

not:

```
[0, 0, 0] then [1, 0, 0]
```

so if wont be `for l in ListA for r in res`

---

thats all

Comment: Thanks, it works well. But can you explain how this works?